# What encoding does c32rtomb convert to?

Tags: c++, unicode, c++11

The functions `c32rtomb` and `mbrtoc32` from `<cuchar>`/`<uchar.h>` are described in the C Unicode TR ([draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1040.pdf)) as performing conversions between UTF-32<sup>1</sup> and "multibyte characters".

> (...) If `s` is not a null 
>   pointer, the `c32rtomb` function determines the number of bytes needed to represent 
>   the multibyte character that corresponds to the wide character given by `c32` 
>   (including any shift sequences), and stores the multibyte character representation in 
>   the array whose first element is pointed to by `s`. (...)

What is this "multibyte character representation"? I'm actually interested in the behaviour of the following program:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <cuchar>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::u32string u32 = U"this is a wide string";
    std::string narrow  = "this is a wide string";
    std::string converted(1000, '\0');
    char* ptr = &converted[0];
    std::mbstate_t state {};
    for(auto u : u32) {
        ptr += std::c32rtomb(ptr, u, &state);
    }
    converted.resize(ptr - &converted[0]);
    assert(converted == narrow);
}
```

Is the assertion in it guaranteed to hold<sup>1</sup>?

---

<sup>1</sup> Working under the assumption that `__STDC_UTF_32__` is defined.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the assertion to be guaranteed to hold true it's necessary that the multibyte encoding used by `c32rtomb()` be the same as the encoding used for string literals, at least as far as the characters actually used in the string.

C99 7.11.1.1/2 specifies that `setlocale()` with the category `LC_CTYPE` affects the behavior of the character handling functions and the multibyte and wide character functions. I don't see any explicit acknowledgement that the effect is to set the multibyte and wide character encodings used, however that is the intent.

So the multibyte encoding used by `c32rtomb()` is the multibyte encoding from the default "C" locale.

C++11 2.14.3/2 specifies that the execution encoding, wide execution encoding, UTF-16, and UTF-32 are used for the corresponding character and string literals. Therefore `std::string narrow` uses the execution encoding to represent that string.

So is the "C" locale encoding of this string the same as the execution encoding of this string?

C99 7.11.1.1/3 specifies that the "C" locale provides "the minimal environment" for C translation. Such an environment would include not only character sets, but also the specific character codes used. So I believe this means not only that the "C" locale must support the  characters required in translation (i.e., the basic character set), but additionally that those characters in the "C" locale must use the same character codes.

All of the characters in your string literals are members of the basic character set, and therefore converting the `char32_t` representation to the `char` "C" locale representation must produce the same sequence of values as the compiler produces for the `char` string literal; the assertion must hold true.

I don't see any suggestion that anything beyond the basic character set is supported in a compatible way between the execution encoding and the "C" locale, so if your string literal used any characters outside the basic character set then there would not be any guarantee that the assertion would hold. Even stipulating extended characters that exist in both the execution character set and the "C" locale, I don't see any requirement that the representations match each other.

Comment: Nice answer.  Just to be clear:  If he adds a call to `setlocale`, the assertion could fail, even if his strings are entirely within the basic character set?

Comment: @Nemo If `setlocale()` were called with an argument other than `"C"`, yes. For example `setlocale("en_US.EBCDIC")` (assuming that's a supported locale with the obvious meaning) on a system where the execution encoding is ASCII compatible would cause `c32rtomb()` to produce EBCDIC strings while `std::string narrow` would remain ASCII encoded.

Answer (score 5):

The TR linked in the question says

> At most `MB_CUR_MAX` bytes are stored.

which is defined (in C99) as

> a positive integer expression with type `size_t` that is the maximum number of bytes in a multibyte character for the extended character set specified by the current locale

I believe this is sufficient evidence that the intent of the TR was to produce the multibyte characters as defined by the currently installed C locale: UTF-8 for `en_US.utf8`, GB18030 for `zh_CN.gb18030`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As I tested, in Linux/MacOSX, c32rtomb converts strings from UTF-32 to the locale specific encodings. You can use nl_langinfo(CODESET) to get the encoding currently used.

However, libc uses "C" locale by default, which uses ISO-8859-1 as the encoding. To change the encoding to which system environment specifies, usually UTF-8 but might be others, use setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "").

In Windows, VS2015+, however, c32rtomb always converts to UTF-8. Since vcruntime does not support UTF-8 locales (only legacy ANSI/OEM locales are supported), if it followed the standard, c32rtomb/c16rtomb would be totally identical to wcrtomb, and no use at all.