# c16rtomb()/c32rtomb() locale-independent conversion?

Tags: c++, c++11, character-encoding, standards-compliance

C++11 introduced the `c16rtomb()`/`c32rtomb()` conversion functions, along with the inverse (`mbrtoc16()`/`mbrtoc32()`). `c16rtomb()` clearly states in the reference documentation [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/c16rtomb):

> The multibyte encoding used by this function is specified by the currently active C locale

The documentation for `c32rtomb()` states the same. Both the C and C++ versions agree that these are locale-dependent conversions (as they should be, according to the naming convention of the functions themselves).

However, MSVC seems to have taken a different approach and made them locale-independent (not using the current C locale) according to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/interpretation-of-multibyte-character-sequences?view=msvc-170). These conversion functions are specified under the heading *Locale-independent multibyte routines*.

C++20 adds to the confusion by including the `c8rtomb()`/`mbrtoc8()` functions, which if locale-independent would basically do nothing, converting UTF-8 input to UTF-8 output.

Two questions arise from this:

1. Do any other compilers actually follow the standard and implement locale-dependent Unicode multibyte conversion routines? I couldn't find any concrete information after extensive searching.
2. Is this a bug in MSVC's implementation?

Comment: Curiously https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53148386/c-unicode-how-do-i-apply-c11-standard-amendment-dr488-fix-to-c11-standard-funct quotes the same page as saying "Convert a UTF-16 wide character into a multibyte character in the current locale." so apparently the documentation *changed*?

Comment: @MooingDuck yep. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/commit/ea5f98a72ec7a0341f6a6acce84ee1f0bfb41b5b

Comment: This appears to be a bug in MSVC's implementation, but I can't fathom *why* they did such a thing.

Comment: Relevant: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42527030/5264388) on SO.